# X11 from remote gnome-session

Tags: ssh, xorg, gnome-terminal

I'd like to run a remote gnome-terminal and have X11 apps show up locally.

This should do the trick but doesn't ("Can't open display"):

```
ssh -Y user@host gnome-terminal
```

This is not what I want, since it's only good for one tab:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -Y user@host'
```

This does the right thing but requires extra steps and window:

```
ssh -Y user@host
gnome-terminal &
```

This does what I want, but with xterm:

```
ssh -Y user@host xterm
```

Ultimately, I'd like to make an alias for the first one, but it doesn't work!
What am I missing?!

Thanks =)

Comment: The first command should work AFAIK - especially since it does when `gnome-terminal` is replaced by `xterm`. What Ubuntu version is it? I know there were some changes in the gnome-terminal-server architecture over recent releases. What does

Comment: All machines are Ubuntu 16.04 and all updates applied to date =\

Answer (score 0):

The command for such thing is `ssh [username@]servername -X` where username@ is optional but useful in order to instruct SSH to use the right username in order to ask for the password only, after which all the GUI of your favorite applications will show up in your desktop instead of the remote desktop.

Additionally, you may wish to use `SSHPass` (Install it with `sudo apt-get install sshpass` in a terminal) in order to create custom **SSH scripts** which will allow you to connect to your server with a single instruction like this:

## local.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh username@server -p [PORT] -X
```

Let's say your SSH server has the `192.168.1.100` IP Address and the user is named `webuser` with a `12345` password, then the command will look like this:

```
sshpass -p "12345" ssh webuser@192.168.1.100 -X
```

- Remember it is important that the `-X` must be uppercase.

After giving the proper execution permissions via `sudo chmod +x local.sh` you can invoke it in a terminal via `./local.sh`

If you wish to go further, you can place this inside your `/usr/bin` directory so that you can invoke it in a terminal or launcher directly via `local.sh` or you can rename it to a single word command like `sshlocal`

*Now. Once you are connected to the server, you don't need to open a terminal. All the commands are executed as if you were in a local terminal in the server. **BUT:** If you wish to execute `gnome-terminal`, a remote GUI for `gnome-terminal` will appear on you screen.*

Give this a try and please inform if you succeed.

### Useful information

```
 -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
         basis in a configuration file.
     X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
     ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
     user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
     through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able
     to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.

     For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
     extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y
     option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for
     more information.


   -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
             subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ssh.1.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, BUT your ssh pass solution is a bad security risk- keeping passwords in plaintext is never a good idea.    Better to use automatic login with authentication keys.  Thanks anyway =)

Comment: It is yet a solution for people who won't try to blow the earth with a computer. If you don't mind I'll keep this answer just in case that somebody else find it useful.